# Converting byte[] to string efficiently

Tags: c#, io

I am working on a hobby project (simple / efficient datastore). My current concern is regarding the performance of reading data from disk (binary) and populating my objects.

My goal is to create a simple store optimized for read performance (for mobile) that is much faster than reading from SQL database or CSV.

After profiling the application, when I read data from disk (~1000 records = 240 ms) records most of the time is spent in the method "set(byte[])":

```
// data layout:
// strings are stored as there UTF-8 representation in a byte array
// within a "row", the first two bytes contain the length in bytes of the string data
// my data store also supports other types (which are much faster) - not shown below.
class myObject : IRow
{
  public string Name;
  public string Title;
  // and so on
  public void set(byte[] row_buffer)
  {
     int offset = 0;
     short strLength = 0;

     // Name - variable about 40 bytes 
     strLength = BitConverter.ToInt16(row_buffer, offset);
     offset += 2;
     Name = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(row_buffer, offset, strLength);
     offset += strLength;

     // Path - variable about 150 bytes
     strLength = BitConverter.ToInt16(row_buffer, offset);
     offset += 2;
     Path = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(row_buffer, offset, strLength);
     offset += strLength;

     // and so on
  }
}
```

Further remarks:

- The data is read as binary from disk.
- for each row in the file, a new object is created and the function set(row_buffer) is called.
- Reading the stream into the row_buffer (using br.Read(row_Buffer, 0, rowLengths[i])) consumes ~ 10% of the time
- Converting the bytes (GetString) to string consumes about 88% of the time

-> I don't understand why creating strings is so expensive :(

Any idea, how I can improve the performance? I am limited to "safe C#" code only.

Thanks for reading.

***EDIT***

I need to create the Objects to run my Linq queries. I would like to defer object creation but failed to find a way at this stage. See my other SO question: [Implement Linq query on byte[] for my own type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21016263/implement-linq-query-on-byte-for-my-own-type)

Comment: Strings are stored Unicode in memory, which means UTF8 data needs to be processed byte by byte.  If you don't need to use a String at that very moment defer that conversion until you do.

Comment: @PeterRitchie yes, you have a very good point and I investigated this too. I have another SO question, why I cannot defer object creation to a later point. I have updated the question to include the reference to my other question.

Comment: How do you mean 'reading the row_buffer consumes ~ 10% of the time'? Is this merely copying byte arrays?

Comment: @AntonTykhyy Thanks for pointing out. I have clarified the statement. I am reading a stream into a fixed byte[]. What I wanted to show is that IO doesn't seem to be the bottleneck.

Comment: 1000 records, how many bytes per record?

Comment: @AntonTykhyy around 100 - 1000 bytes (strings are of variable size). Please note that the performance numbers are from a mobile device (Windows Phone 7) - cannot be compared to a Desktop with SSDs :)

Comment: That's very important! Still I wonder, because 240ms for reading half a megabyte of data seems very slow. Also, how are you measuring time? Does it make a difference if you read the whole file into a memory stream first and fill your rows from that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44901/discussion-between-jasper-and-anton-tykhyy)