# Implement Linq query on byte[] for my own type

Tags: c#, .net, database, performance, linq

I have my own little database I am working on (for learning purposes). Data is stored as binary on disk. 
I can do a full table scan and my database will return each "row" as a byte[] row_buffer.
The row_buffer contains the fields of each row. Logically, it looks like:

`row_buffer = [[var_string][int32][var_string]]`

I have the column defined in a "Table Definition" structure. Point is, I know the position of each data field in each row.

Now, I want to implement Linq capabilities to query data from my database (simple queries):

```
var DemoTable = new Table<PeopleClass>();
var result = DemoTable.Where(p => p.Name == "Peter").Select(p => p).ToList();
```

In my Table class, I have implemented the following logic:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Where(Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
  foreach (var item in this.rows)
  {
    if (predicate(item)) yield return item;
  }
}
```

Note: this.rows is a List that contains all records of the database.

My issue is that generating PeopleClass objects for each row is very inefficient (due to converting bytes[] to string). I want to defer the creation as much as possible.

Currently, I am investigating to convert the condition to byte[] and compare that directly agains my rows. But I have failed so far.

How can I implement `IEnumerable<T> Where(Func<T, bool> predicate)` to directly operate on the row_buffer instead of having to generate the PeopleClass objects first? Only the successfull hits should be converted to PeopleClass objects.

I did not find a way to extract the condition (which field name e.g. "Name" and which value for the field is required) in the predicate.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You probably have to parse the predicate as expression to be efficient with that. EF does this and perhaps you can take a look into their source codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, it looks like you need to create a LINQ provider, you don't need to implement `Where` etc., that's already been done.  I'd start there, before looking at any possible performance issues.

You need to create an `IQueryable` with your custom provider to perform the specific logic of decoding the expression-tree etc.  This is quite complicated, have a a look at [MSDN: Walkthrough: Creating an IQueryable LINQ Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546158.aspx) or [Writing custom LINQ provider](http://weblogs.asp.net/mehfuzh/archive/2007/10/04/writing-custom-linq-provider.aspx)
, there's lots of tutorials around.

Edit: removed idiot improvement.

Comment: "var result = DemoTable.Select(p => p.Name == "Peter").ToList();" This makes no sense? You would have a list of booleans...